# How to get the Powerstatus?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

How can i get the Powerstatus? 
In Windows is it easy:

```
SystemInformation.PowerStatus.BatteryChargeStatus.ToString();
```

How can i do this in MonoDevelop?

Comment: have you tried it in mono?

Comment: yes i have. 
I get the Error: "The name 'SystemInformation' does not exist in the current kontext"

Comment: `SystemInformation` is defined at `System.Windows.Forms` assembly and I doubt it has implementation in mono. Check their documentation regarding battery status information

Comment: I have look at http://docs.go-mono.com/ but there is nothing about this topic.